# submitting a form that has a picture into a mysql server using php

Tags: php, forms

I am making a form that allows a user to create a page that has a qr code to link it to the page. I am only having one problem, I cant get the picture to upload to the database and display after the form has been submitted. it displays the file name of the photo just not the photo.

here is my form code

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();


<html>
<head>


</head>

<title>create </title>
<center> <font size="+5"> Create </center>
<body background="">
<p



<table align="center" cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="1">
<form name="createTeaOffer" action="submit.php" method="get">

<tr> <td> <font size="+3"> Headline:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="hea"> </td> </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td> <font size="+3"> Photo:  </td> <td> <input type="file" name="pho"> </td> </tr>
<br /> 
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Description: </td> <td><input name="des" type="textarea"> </td>   </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Contact Method: </td> <td> <input name="con" type="radio" value="email" name="email" >Email <input type="radio" value="phone"   method="get" name="phone"> Phone </td> </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Email or Phone: </td> <td> <input name="ema" type="text"> </td> </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Location: </td> <td> <input name="loc" type="text"> </td> </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Expiration (yyyy-mm-dd): </td> <td> <input name="exp" type="date"> </td> </tr>
<br />
<tr> <td><font size="+3">Distance: </td> <td> <input name="dis" type="text"> </td></tr>
<br />
</font></table>
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my submit code

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$template = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><!--TITLE--></title>




</head>

<body>
This page belongs to user $myusername<p><p>
QR Code: <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url....%2F"<!--PAGENAME-->"&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com"><p> 
Headline: <!--COMMENT--><p>
Photo: <!--PHOTO--><p>
Description: <!--DESC--><p>
Contact By: <!--CONBY--><p>
Contact information: <!--EMP--><p>
Location: <!--LOC--><p>
page expires on: <!--EXP--><p>
Distance: <!--DIS--><p>
<p>
Webpage URL: <!--PAGENAME-->
<p>
Please click <a href="/">Here</a> to go back to the homepage.

</body>
</html>

EOD;

//handle the posted form
if(isset($_POST['hea1'])&&isset($_POST['pho1'])){
//replace the areas of the template with the posted values
$page = str_replace('<!--TITLE-->',htmlentities($_POST['hea1']),$template);
$page = str_replace('<!--COMMENT-->',htmlentities($_POST['hea1']),$page);
$page = str_replace('<!--PHOTO-->',htmlentities($_POST['pho1']),$page); 
$page = str_replace('<!--PAGENAME-->',htmlentities($_POST['wp1']),$page);


    $page = str_replace('<!--DESC-->',htmlentities($_POST['des1']),$page);
        $page = str_replace('<!--CONBY-->',htmlentities($_POST['con1']),$page);
            $page =   
str_replace('<!--EMP-->',htmlentities($_POST['ema1']),$page);
   $page =  str_replace('<!--LOC-->',htmlentities($_POST['loc1']),$page);               
$page = str_replace('<!--EXP-->',htmlentities($_POST['exp1']),$page);   
$page = str_replace('<!--DIS-->',htmlentities($_POST['dis1']),$page);   


//create a name for the new page
$pagename = md5($_POST['hea1']).'.html';

//db connect & select
$db=mysql_connect('localhost','streich','U4iwcjn3Hi&d');
mysql_select_db('streich_users');

//check if page already exists
//    $result = mysql_query('SELECT page_url from pages WHERE url="'.mysql_real_escape_string($pagename).'"');
//    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1){
//        $notice = '<p>Page already created <b>./pages/'.$pagename.'</b></p>';
//    }else{
    //inset new page into db
    mysql_query('INSERT into pages  (`page_name`,`disc`,`page_url`,`username`,
    `start_date`,`end_date`,`location`,`email`,`phone`,`photo`)VALUES(
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['hea1'])).'",
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['dis1'])).'",
    "'.$pagename.'","'.$myusername.'","'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['crd1'])).'",
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['exp1'])).'",
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['loc1'])).'",
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['ema1'])).'",
    "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['pho1'])).'")');
    //put the created content to file
    file_put_contents('./tearoffer/'.$pagename,$page);
    //make a notice to show the user
    $notice = '<p>New Page created <b>./page/'.$pagename.'</b></p>';
    $fulllink = 'url/'.$pagename.'';
    //header("location:/tearoffer/$pagename"); 
    echo $fulllink;
    ?>
    <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url......%2Fpages%2F<? echo $pagename ?>&choe=UTF-8" title="Link"><p> 
    <?
  //  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Make page example</title>
<style type="text/css">
.prevpage {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #093;
background-color: #333;
}
body {

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//if the notice is set then display it
if(isset($notice)){echo $notice;} ?>
<ul><li class="prevpage"><b>Headline:</b> <?php echo $_GET['hea']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Photo:</b> <?php echo $_GET['pho']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Description:</b> <?php echo $_GET['des']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Contact by:</b> <?php echo $_GET['con']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>E-Mail or Phone:</b> <?php echo $_GET['ema']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Location:</b> <?php echo $_GET['loc']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Expiration (yyyy-mm-dd):</b> <?php echo $_GET['exp']; ?></li>
<li class="prevpage"></li>
<li class="prevpage"><b>Distance:</b> <?php echo $_GET['dis']; ?></li>
</ul>/
<form method="POST" action="">
<input name="hea1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['hea']; ?>"> 
<input name="pho1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['pho']; ?>">  
<input name="des1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['des']; ?>"> 
<input name="crd1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">   
<input name="con1" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['con']; ?>> 
<input name="ema1" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['ema']; ?>> 
<input name="loc1" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['loc']; ?>> 
<input name="exp1" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['exp']; ?>>
<input name="dis1" type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_GET['dis']; ?>>
<input name="tst1" type="hidden" value="Thank you for using pages.">
<?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wp1" value="' . htmlspecialchars($pagename) . '" />'."\n";
?>



<input type="submit" value="submit preview">
</form>



</body></html>
```

Comment: and read this, there are multiple things wrong with your form: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Also it is a terrible idea to layout a page with tables use CSS instead. Here is a link explaining why http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Comment: I would learn a lot more about general html/css also php/mysql a great resource in my opinion is TutsPlus it costs money but it is cheap and there is a wealth of information there

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer, I can't really explain the actual code, but you can't upload an image to a "database" because databases are (normally) text based unless you use image encoding. If you mean uploading to your site's filesystem, refer to this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and add the image URL to your database. You can then use `<?php echo '<img src="' . $imageURL . '">' ?>` to echo the image on the user's profile.

Also like dagon said, you have some problems with your html for example you put the title in the body section when it should be in the head section. I would also recommend using a $_POST request, not a $_GET request because it's more secure. Get better at the basics of html, there are plenty of resources available. The use of the font tag would make a normal web developer cry in pain because it's not even supposed to be used any more. Learn CSS, dude (put `<style>td { font-size:15px }</style>` in the head section).

Finally, calling a form field name things like "loc" and "con" are terrible ways to name a field. If you're the only one writing the code, then why should you make the names so confusing?